# Issu with varnish-ban-manager installation, using vhost in AWS

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, dns, varnish, vhosts

I've installed varnish-ban-manager (https://github.com/dot2code/varnish-bans-manager) and I'm currently configuring it's DNS name.
The thing is that I've set in Route53 (DNS service in AWS) to use name http:// purge.domain.com / pointing to http:// varnish_server_name.com/. The thing is, if I test with http :// purge.domain .com:9000/ it works normally, but using http: //purge.domain.com/ will send me a "your request cannot be processed" (in a varnish error screen).
Any ideas why this could be happening? I've test this with the ip address of this vm and works perfectly too..
Here's the vhost config file:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName purge.domain.com
  ServerAlias purge.domain.com

  ProxyPass             /    http://varnish_server.domain:9200/
  ProxyPassReverse      /    http://purge.domain.com/

  # Logging
  ErrorLog logs/server-error_log
  CustomLog logs/server-access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Note: i've replaced my real domain for "domain" just in case.

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I've added some lines to vhost:

ServerName http:// purge.comain.com

ProxyPass /        http:// varnish_server:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse      /    http:// varnish_server:9000/

ErrorLog logs/purge. cloud-turner.com.ar-error_log
  CustomLog logs/purge. cloud-turner.com.ar-access_log combined

And added proxy.conf (/etc/httpd/conf.d/) with this line
ProxyPreserveHost on

And that's it!